# Details on JAX-WS webservices

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I am completely new to web-services, currently I am trying to learn JAX-WS from online documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html

The document gives steps on how to create and deploy web-services using `Netbeans IDE`, I have followed the steps and able to deploy and test the examples. But I am not able to understand how the application is deployed to `Glassfish server` and if we need to have any additional configurations that tells to the server that my project contains web-services code.

Also I am not clear on what are the elements of `SOAP` request and response xml files? Also elements for `WSDL` file.

Please let me know if there is an alternate documentation or book that gives me these details?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) entry on Wikipedia actually has a pretty good rundown of the WSDL elements. As for the SOAP requests and responses, they will be dictated by the WSDL you built.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, the reason of your struggle is lack of knowledge about web applications development in java. Basically web services are packaged as web applications and deployed on web servers such as tomcat, glassfish, etc. IDE such as Netbeans, Eclipse provides a way to deploy web applications on the associated web server. Actually these IDEs simply create the war(web application archive) files, copy it the web server deployment directory and starts the web server.

Learning about web applications and your choice of web server will help you learn about how JAX-WS web services are deployed.

Axis is just one of the frameworks available to write webservices in java. Most of the avaialble frameworks comply to JAX-JWS and makes it easier to write web services.

Hope this info helps.

Comment: Thanks Juned, but when I searched in internet for creating web-services using eclipse IDE, I get the answers that says eclipse used Apache axis, so in case of Netbeans what is the framework used internally? I mean did I use any framework when I built the examples as mentioned in the online document?

Comment: As far as i know, neither Eclipse nor Netbeans comes up with any frameworks to develop web service. Important to note that it is not necessary to use a framework either, its just that it will make your coding easier. What i recommend you is that have some patience, first learn about web development, web servers, then jump on IDE + web development. Finally jump on any JAX-WS framework to do web service development. It will take a while but surely worth learning to have the correct in-depth knowledge. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to understand web service types and try to implement as per your requirement

A SOAP message is a XML document which is used to transmit your data. WSDL is an XML document which describes how to connect and make requests to your web service.

Basically SOAP messages are the data you transmit, WSDL tells you what you can do and how to make the calls.

**If they are different, then when should I use SOAP messages and when should I use WSDL's?** Soap is structure you apply to your message/data for transfer. WSDLs are used only to determine how to make calls to the service in the first place. Often this is a one time thing when you first add code to make a call to a particular webservice.

- [SOAP Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) are standard-based and supported by almost every
  software platform: They rely heavily in XML and have support for
  transactions, security, asynchronous messages and many other issues.
  It’s a pretty big and complicated standard, but covers almost every
  messaging situation. On the other side, [RESTful services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) relies of
  HTTP protocol and verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to interchange
  messages in any format, preferable JSON and XML. It’s a pretty
  simple and elegant architectural approach.

  - As in every topic in the Java World, there are several libraries to
    build/consume Web Services. In the SOAP Side you have the [JAX-WS
    standard](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) and [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/), and in REST you can use [Restlets](http://restlet.org/) or [Spring
    REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html) Facilities among other libraries.

  **RESTful Services scenarios**

  1. If you have limited bandwidth
  2. If your operations are stateless: No information is preserved from
     one invocation to the next one, and each request is treated
     independently.
  3. If your clients require caching.

  **SOAP Services scenarios**

  1. If you require asynchronous processing
  2. If you need formal contract/Interfaces
  3. In your service operations are stateful: For example, you store
     information/data on a request and use that stored data on the next
     one.

Comment: Thanks Shyam, which is preferred to use, is it JAX-WS standard or Apache Axis? I use Eclipse IDE, so can I build JAX-WS standard with Eclipse IDE, because eclipse comes with Apache Axis by default.

Comment: @user2065083 yes you can build JAX-WS by using  eclipse.http://javapostsforlearning.blogspot.in/2013/03/jaxws-web-service-eclipse-tutorial.html also follow some other tutorial's.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyam, can you please refer me to some good documentation or book that gives me complete details. Because the online document for web-services do not have all the information. I understand that there are so many examples that I can get from internet but looking for some standard doc or good book.

Comment: @user2065083 Java 7 JAX-WS Web Services by Deepak Vohra